# Determining System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send result

Tags: c#, exception, sendmail

I am trying to summarize the outcomes from `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send` using an enum. This is so I know whether I should retry sending the email and hopefully prevent duplicate emails being sent.

```
public enum MailSendStatus {
    None,
    Sent,
    ErrorCannotSend,
    TryAgain,
    SentMaybe
}
```

I have caught all the exceptions from `Send` and split out the `SmtpException.StatusCode`s from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpstatuscode(v=vs.80).aspx. Does the breakdown look right? Or is there a better way to do this?

```
try {
    smtp.Send(msg);
} catch (ArgumentNullException e) {
    return MailSendStatus.ErrorCannotSend;
} catch (ObjectDisposedException e) {
    return MailSendStatus.ErrorCannotSend;
} catch (InvalidOperationException e) {
    return MailSendStatus.ErrorCannotSend;
} catch (SmtpFailedRecipientsException e) {
    return MailSendStatus.ErrorCannotSend;
} catch (SmtpException e) {
    switch(e.StatusCode) {
        case SmtpStatusCode.BadCommandSequence:
        case SmtpStatusCode.MailboxNameNotAllowed:
        case SmtpStatusCode.HelpMessage:
        case SmtpStatusCode.SyntaxError:
        case SmtpStatusCode.SystemStatus:
            return MailSendStatus.ErrorCannotSend;
        case SmtpStatusCode.CannotVerifyUserWillAttemptDelivery:
        case SmtpStatusCode.UserNotLocalWillForward:
            return MailSendStatus.SentMaybe;
        case SmtpStatusCode.ClientNotPermitted:
        case SmtpStatusCode.CommandNotImplemented:
        case SmtpStatusCode.CommandParameterNotImplemented:
        case SmtpStatusCode.CommandUnrecognized:
        case SmtpStatusCode.ExceededStorageAllocation:
        case SmtpStatusCode.GeneralFailure:
        case SmtpStatusCode.InsufficientStorage:
        case SmtpStatusCode.LocalErrorInProcessing:
        case SmtpStatusCode.MailboxBusy:
        case SmtpStatusCode.MailboxUnavailable:
        case SmtpStatusCode.MustIssueStartTlsFirst:
        case SmtpStatusCode.ServiceClosingTransmissionChannel:
        case SmtpStatusCode.ServiceNotAvailable:
        case SmtpStatusCode.ServiceReady:
        case SmtpStatusCode.StartMailInput:
        case SmtpStatusCode.TransactionFailed:
        case SmtpStatusCode.UserNotLocalTryAlternatePath:
            return MailSendStatus.TryAgain;
        case SmtpStatusCode.Ok:
            break;
    }
} catch (Exception e) { 
    return MailSendStatus.SentMaybe;
}
return MailSendStatus.Sent;
```

Comment: There are a few cases in here I don't quite agree with. For example, `SmtpStatusCode.CommandUnrecognized`, I think, would indicate that the smtp server or the client are communicating in an incompatible way that couldn't be rectified by retrying.

Answer (score 2):

```
catch (ArgumentNullException e) {    return MailSendStatus.ErrorCannotSend;} catch 
(ObjectDisposedException e) {    return MailSendStatus.ErrorCannotSend;} catch 
(InvalidOperationException e) {    return MailSendStatus.ErrorCannotSend;
```

I dont like this. ArgumentNull, ObjectDisposed are programming errors (as is InvalidOperation). You should not break them down to a SMTP error but have them fixed. Fpr this, crashing the program is good (and putting out a stack trace). Approach "fail fast". Dont rethriow exceptions you dont know how to handle, and InvalidOperationException, ObjectDisposedException indicate something is wrong with the state, ArbumentNullException is a usage / ui error.

Comment: I have omitted the log statements for clarity, but yes those should mostly be caught in development. I just included all the exceptions on the msdn page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc.aspx

Comment: I dont like that. Really. The problem is that it makes it very hard to catch a real bud further down. I never hide internal errors and want them as visible as possible for fast cleanup.

Comment: if i remove those cases from the catch tree, the generic `(Exception e)` will trigger, returning a "may have sent" status code, which is not right, it was definitately an error, i suppose i could re-throw the exception

Comment: AH, yes and no. I NEVER (some exceptions apply) have ANY generic Exception handler. If i do not expect an exception, the app better fals. Exception is MOSTLY interface to external libray where I take the freedom to log them in an exception handler. THe idea being: you do not catch an exception you dont know how to deal with, and unknown exceptions are exactly that kind of exception.